# Approach to a thread safe program

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

All,

What should be the approach to writing a thread safe program. Given a problem statement, my perspective is:

1 > Start of with writing the code for a single threaded environment.
2 > Underline the fields which would need atomicity and replace with possible concurrent classes
3 > Underline the critical section and enclose them in synchronized
4 > Perform test for deadlocks

Does anyone have any suggestions on the other approaches or improvements to my approach. So far, I can see myself enclosing most of the code in synchronized blocks and I am sure this is not correct.

Programming in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing correct multi-threaded code is hard, and there is not a magic formula or set of steps that will get you there. But, there are some guidelines you can follow.

Personally I wouldn't start with writing code for a single threaded environment and then converting it to multi-threaded. Good multi-threaded code is designed with multi-threading in mind from the start. Atomicity of fields is just one element of concurrent code.

You should decide on what areas of the code need to be multi-threaded (in a multi-threaded app, typically not everything needs to be threadsafe). Then you need to design how those sections will be threadsafe. Methods of making one area of the code threadsafe may be different than making other areas different. For example, understanding whether there will be a high volume of reading vs writing is important and might affect the types of locks you use to protect the data.

Immutability is also a key element of threadsafe code. When elements are immutable (i.e. cannot be changed), you don't need to worry about multiple threads modifying them since they cannot be changed. This can greatly simplify thread safety issues and allow you to focus on where you will have multiple data readers and writers.

Understanding details of concurrency in Java (and details of the Java memory model) is very important. If you're not already familiar with these concepts, I recommend reading Java Concurrency In Practice http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/.

Comment: +1 for immutability. Minimizing writable state mitigates many concurrency concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **final** and **immutable** fields wherever possible, any other data that you want to change add inside:

```
  synchronized (this) {
     // update
  }
```

And remember, sometimes stuff brakes, and if that happens, you don't want to prolong the program execution by taking every possible way to counter it - instead "fail fast".

Answer (score 1):

As you have asked about "thread-safety" and not concurrent performance, then your approach is essentially sound. However, a thread-safe program that uses synchronisation probably does not scale much in a multi cpu environment with any level of contention on your structure/program.

Personally I like to try and identify the highest level state changes and try and think about how to make them atomic, and have the state changes move from one immutable state to another – copy-on-write if you like. Then the actual write can be either a compare-and-set operation on an atomic variable or a synchronised update or whatever strategy works/performs best (as long as it safely publishes the new state).

This can be a bit difficult to structure if your new state is quite different (requires updates to several fields for instance), but I have seen it very successfully solve concurrent performance issues with synchronised access.

Answer (score 1):

Buy and read Brian Goetz's "Java Concurrency in Practice".

Answer (score 0):

Any variables (memory) accessible by multiple threads potentially at the same time, need to be protected by a synchronisation mechanism.